# Error of finite difference for solving heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation

Consider solving the heat equation $u_t=u_{xx}$ on $[0,2\pi]$ with periodic boundary condition. Numerically, we can solve it using second order finite difference in space discretization and Euler-Backward in time.

One can get the following error estimate:

$$
\left\|U^{n}-u^{n}\right\|_{\infty, h} \leq C t_{n}\left(h^{2}+k\right) \max _{t \leq t_{n}}|u(\cdot, t)|_{\mathcal{C}^{4}}, \quad \text { for } t_{n} \geq 0
$$
where $u^n=u(\cdot,t_n)$, $U^n$ is the numerical solution at time $t_n$, $h$ is the size of the mesh and $k$ is the size of time step.

In the following figure, I plot the error $\left\|U^{n}-u^{n}\right\|_{\infty, h}$ for each $n$: The true solution is set to be $u(x,t)=\sin(x)e^{-t}$
[image]

What I confused here is that why the error will decrease after a certain of time? At each time step, there will be some errors added to the solution. So, I thought the error might be as a nondecreasing function of time t.

Comment: As $t$ gets large, the true solution decays to zero, as does the numerical approximation. Moreover, the true solution's decay gets slower and slower. So the numerical estimate has the opportunity to "catch up" a bit. If you could take $t = \infty$, both the true and numerical solutions should be identically zero

Comment: The true solution and the numerical solution tend to the same equilibrium. Therefore their difference tends to zero. Any function converging uniformly to 0 would become more and more close to the solution.

Comment: Note that a difference tending to 0 does not mean a better correlation: if several balls roll in a bowl, they all finish at the bottom of the bowl, even if their movements are not correlated.